# iOS 10 Facebook graph.facebook.com SSL Error - FBSDK secure network request failed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

After a week of research I just cannot resolve this bug:

An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

```
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3
```

Snippet from Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
  <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)APP_ID</string>
</array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fbapi20130214</string>
  <string>fbapi20130410</string>
  <string>fbapi20130702</string>
  <string>fbapi20131010</string>
  <string>fbapi20131219</string>
  <string>fbapi20140410</string>
  <string>fbapi20140116</string>
  <string>fbapi20150313</string>
  <string>fbapi20150629</string>
  <string>fbauth</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>graph</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true />
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>facebook.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true />
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false />
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true />
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.2</string>
    </dict>
    <key>fbcdn.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true />
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false />
    </dict>
    <key>akamaihd.net</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true />
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false />
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

I've also enabled keychain sharing.

I think I've tried all the solutions found on the internet and still no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So After I while I think i found the answer to the bug.

I was loading profile image from graph api with https and it should be loaded via http.

Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/facebook_user_id/picture?type=large
```

Should be

```
http://graph.facebook.com/facebook_user_id/picture?type=large
```

Notice the s missing from https protocol, which was the key difference.